# Simultaneously host website on multiple platforms?

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting, heroku, amazon-aws

Is it possible to host my site `www.example.com` that sells T-Shirts on multiple services simultaneously  e.g. AWS EC2 (or Heroku) & my personal box (let's call it MyBox)?
I would typically serve the user from my MyBox but if it goes down or it's overloaded, the additional traffic would be routed to AWS. How will the databases stay coherent in this case?

Comment: The question in the title doesn't completely match the question in the first sentence, and there's two more that would require broad, opinion-based answers... Can you edit it down to just one specific question?

Comment: @dan Edited title & detail.

Comment: Theoretically, you are looking for a smart load balancer. The load balancer has x MyBox(es) and y AWS_Box(es). Only when MyBox(es) are unreachable/overloaded send traffic to AWS_Box(es). Although I have never played with an LB myself, I assume this should be supported by them.

Comment: Where would the LB run? Ideally at DNS level?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Scalr, it auto scales servers, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiLXsNtt-JE

It's open source, but they also have a hosted version.